# Is await mandatory to use with async method in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, async-await

I was discussing with someone else about the use of async/await in JavaScript and we didn't agree.

Personally, I only use await when I need to wait for the async method to be finished. If I don't need it to finish to continue, I don't.
E.g.:

```
async myAsyncMethod() {
    axios.get(`/foo`)
    .then((response) => {
        this.foo = response.data;
     }).catch (exception) {
        //do something with exception
        this.foo = null;
    };
}
```

If I need the data right away, I call:

```
await myAsyncMethod();
```

If I don't, I do:

```
myAsyncMethod();
```

Is it not correct to do this last one? The other person maintained that I should not. If so, would it be possible to explain to me why.

---

I've edited the myAsyncMethod() to be more precise. So my questions implies that that I catch errors and that I know that 'foo' is either null either field with data at some point... The point is that I don't need those data right away and I've got other things to do that don't require it.

Comment: short answer no. longer answer also no. await waits for async to resolve or reject. if you dont need the results, you wont need to await.

Comment: an `async` function is a function that returns a promise, `await` just unwraps the promise and extracts the result. So it's totally legit calling an async function without `await`, but just mind that it's just a reference to the promise and not the returned value

Comment: I advise you to read the free book "You don't know JS". Everything will be clear

Comment: If you _don't_ `await` it (or otherwise handle the error, e.g. with `.catch`), and it errors, you have an "unhandled promise rejection". What happens next is up to the runtime; in [Node 15 and up](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/doc/changelogs/CHANGELOG_V15.md#throw-on-unhandled-rejections---33021), your app will crash.

Answer (score 0):

An `async` function without an `await` expression will run synchronously.

The `await` expression causes `async` function execution to pause until a Promise is settled (that is, fulfilled or rejected), and to resume execution of the async function after fulfillment.

So, in your case, the `myAsyncMethod` will return an unsettled promise unless you await it.

References:

1. [Async function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)
2. [Await operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await)